# Qgis map composer shows a huge red cross

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-2.4

I can show this best by a picture:

[image: Figure]

This cross also shows when I export it as raster or pdf. What is it and how can I get rid of it?

I am using Qgis 2.4 and the map was done with the help of the Grass plugin `AniMove` on Linux Mint.

Comment: can you help me? I'm trying to modify the plug-in QuickEsport! if possible should be exported to PDF, not only the attribute of the "dbf" the pictures!

Comment: This is not the place to ask a question, Please consider starting your own question by clicking the "ask question" button on the top of the screen.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's caused by a picture item with an invalid or corrupt picture path. Click on the item and check the image source.

Comment: Ok.. it was very difficult to select the picture... I don't know how it happened, but after I while I managed to select the picture and delete it. Thanks!